# Can't reload data in tableView after parsing XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview

I'm starting NSURLConnection, parsing XML, initialize array from this XML, and show it in the tableView. In connectionDidFinishLoading I'm trying [self.tableView reloadData, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

my .h file:

```
@interface catalogViewController : UITableViewController // 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * titleArr;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * contentArr; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * ImageURLArr;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * dateArr;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * priceArr;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary * xmlDictionary; 
 @property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * IDArr; 
@property (nonatomic) BOOL * didDataLoaded;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@end
```

My .m file:

```
#import "catalogViewController.h"
#import "XMLReader.h"
@interface catalogViewController () 
@end 


@implementation catalogViewController 

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style { 
self = [super initWithStyle:style]; 
if (self) { } return self; 
} 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-CONNECTIONS METHOD START-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[_receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [_receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[connection release]; 
[_receivedData release];
 NSString *errorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error description], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]]; NSLog(@"%@",errorString);
[errorString release];
}

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-GET FULL DATA HERE-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=- 
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
 NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-XMLPARSER PART START-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- //
NSString *testXMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL usedEncoding:nil error:nil];

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Parse the XML into a dictionary-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
NSError *parseError = nil; 
_xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-XMLPARSER PART END-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
_titleArr =[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"]; 
_IDArr =[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"id"] valueForKey:@"text"];
_priceArr=[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"price"] valueForKey:@"text"]; 
_ImageURLArr=[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"img"] valueForKey:@"text"]; 

 [connection release];
[_receivedData release];
[dataString release]; 

_didDataLoaded=TRUE;

[_myTableView reloadData]; // IBOutlet property 
[self.tableView reloadData]; //default

} 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-Connection methods END-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad]; 

_didDataLoaded=FALSE; 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-XMLPARSER PART START-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=START Shit with connection-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=
 NSString* params = @"request_params";
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my URL"];
 NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connection) {
NSLog(@"Connecting...");
_receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain]; 
} else {
NSLog(@"Connecting error"); 
}
} 

//-=-==-=-=--=-==-=-=-=-=-=--=-==---=-=--==-=-=-=-=-TableView methods-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (_didDataLoaded == FALSE) {
return 1;
} 
else return self.titleArr.count; 
} 

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1; }

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"creatures"]; 
UIImage *creatureImage = nil; 

if (_didDataLoaded == FALSE) {
cell.textLabel.text=@"Downloading...";
cell.detailTextLabel.text= @"downloading...";
} else {
 cell.textLabel.text = [self.titleArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
cell.detailTextLabel.text= _IDArr[indexPath.row]; 
NSString *img = self.ImageURLArr[indexPath.row];
creatureImage =[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img]]]; cell.imageView.image = creatureImage; 
} 
return cell; 
}

 @end
```

XML downloading - OK, parsing - OK, initialising arrays - OK. But when I start project I have exception on the  line `NSLog(@"%@", self.titleArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` - says: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1)
How can I understand it's means that it's trying initialize array when it's not prepare. My problem is i can't delay tableView methods or what? How can i fix it? I'm trying fix itfor some days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your titleArr is deallocated from memory and then you are requesting object of it so it is giving you a crash. So allocate memory to array by this way.

```
_titleArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"]];
```

Comment: Can you explain please, why it's  deallocated from memory?

Comment: It is not allocated and after used once it will free up memory. So if you want your object should stay in memory then you need allocate it and release it on dealloc method.

Comment: Thanks. Can you aswer another my question please? In ViewDidLoad I appeal to the server with a query parameter <type> 0 </type>, and it's returned for me string, after all conversion a have in tableView 4 rows - titles, and when i push on some of this titles, all process (connection to the server, parsing, arrays initialising, ) must be repeated. In didSelectedRowAtIndexPath I have to transmit section ID (so that the server sent me the correct data). How can I do it correctly? I'm establish connection in ViewDidLoad, how i can call it again?

Comment: @user2987175 lets not break SO Rules. if you have another question post it up :), you will surely get help on that.

Comment: have a look here  please ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952691/how-to-reloaddata-in-tableview-with-didselectedrowatindexpath-and-call-group-of

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough it's not recommended way but the following can provide a solution to you

```
self.tableView.delegate = nil;

self.tableView.datasource  = nil;
```

and when safely your array was populated with the xml data set back to

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;

self.tableView.datasource  = self;
```