# How to reloadData in tableView with didSelectedRowAtIndexPath and call group of methods in it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I'm starting NSURLConnection, parsing XML, initialize array from this XML, and show it in the tableView. In ViewDidLoad I appeal to the server with a query parameter  0 , and it's returned for me string, after all conversion a have in tableView 4 rows - titles, and when i push on some of this titles, all process (connection to the server, parsing, arrays initialising, ) must be repeated. In didSelectedRowAtIndexPath I have to transmit section ID (so that the server sent me the correct data). How can I do it correctly? I'm establish connection in ViewDidLoad, how can I call it again?

My .m file:

```
#import "catalogViewController.h"
#import "XMLReader.h"
@interface catalogViewController () 
@end 


@implementation catalogViewController 

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style { 
self = [super initWithStyle:style]; 
if (self) { } return self; 
} 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-CONNECTIONS METHOD START-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[_receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [_receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[connection release]; 
[_receivedData release];
 NSString *errorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error description], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]]; NSLog(@"%@",errorString);
[errorString release];
}

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-GET FULL DATA HERE-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=- 
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
 NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-XMLPARSER PART START-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- //
NSString *testXMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL usedEncoding:nil error:nil];

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Parse the XML into a dictionary-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
NSError *parseError = nil; 
_xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-XMLPARSER PART END-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
_titleArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"]];
_IDArr = [[NSArray alloc] [[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"id"] valueForKey:@"text"]];
_priceArr= [[NSArray alloc][[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"price"] valueForKey:@"text"]]; 
_ImageURLArr=[[NSArray alloc][[[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"img"] valueForKey:@"text"]]; 

 [connection release];
[_receivedData release];
[dataString release]; 

_didDataLoaded=TRUE;

[_myTableView reloadData]; // IBOutlet property 
[self.tableView reloadData]; //default

} 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-Connection methods END-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad]; 

_didDataLoaded=FALSE; 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-XMLPARSER PART START-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=START Shit with connection-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=
 NSString* params = @"request_params";
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my URL"];
 NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connection) {
NSLog(@"Connecting...");
_receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain]; 
} else {
NSLog(@"Connecting error"); 
}
} 

//-=-==-=-=--=-==-=-=-=-=-=--=-==---=-=--==-=-=-=-=-TableView methods-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (_didDataLoaded == FALSE) {
return 1;
} 
else return self.titleArr.count; 
} 

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1; }

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"creatures"]; 
UIImage *creatureImage = nil; 

if (_didDataLoaded == FALSE) {
cell.textLabel.text=@"Downloading...";
cell.detailTextLabel.text= @"downloading...";
} else {
 cell.textLabel.text = [self.titleArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
cell.detailTextLabel.text= _IDArr[indexPath.row]; 
NSString *img = self.ImageURLArr[indexPath.row];
creatureImage =[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img]]]; cell.imageView.image = creatureImage; 
} 
return cell; 
}

 @end
```

Comment: Create method like - (void)loadDataWithParam:(NSString*)id and call it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the relevant code from viewDidLoad to a specific method, something like:

```
- (void)loadXMLData {
    // Initiate your loading/parsing 
}
```

In viewDidLoad just call this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadXMLData];
}
```

This way you can call [self loadXMLData] multiple times.

However... be careful with calling [tableView reloadData] from inside a UITableViewDelegate method implementation, as this will cause the tableview to call (at least some of the) delegate methods, which can cause recursive loops or other odd behaviour.