# AFNetworking post and get xml data

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I want to post some data on this service using afnetworking and its content type is application/soap+xml.but i got the error

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x9034f00 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://webapp.admin-inapp.com/services/FeedbackService.asmx?op=SendFeedback, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8e31a00> { URL: http://webapp.admin-inapp.com/services/FeedbackService.asmx?op=SendFeedback } { status code: 500, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Length" = 1666;
"Content-Type" = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Fri, 23 May 2014 06:43:32 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
```

} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}

Here is my code

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webapp.admin-inapp.com/services/FeedbackService.asmx?op=SendFeedback"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"9888291933" forKey:@"Number"];
[dict setObject:self.textview.text forKey:@"Feedback"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:string parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

}

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402034/parsing-xml-with-afnetworking

Comment: 500 error indicates something went wrong in server processing your request..

Comment: can you sent your requested URL?

Comment: it gives me same error.

Comment: share your requested url here

Comment: http://webapp.admin-inapp.com/services/FeedbackService.asmx?op=SendFeedback this is your requested URL?

Comment: preamkumar http://webapp.admin-inapp.com/services/FeedbackService.asmx?op=SendFeedback

Comment: Your title says that you want to post XML data, but your code will not POST XML, but rather will use `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` (i.e. a it will `POST` a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request). Does your request need to be in XML? If so, you have to construct that XML yourself. If your web service supported JSON, iOS does that pretty seamlessly. And iOS parses XML requests pretty well, too (with `NSXMLParser`), but creating XML requests requires a little more coding on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL and objects.

I think this is SOAP web service. you must sent request differently for SOAP web service.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                     "<soap:Body>\n"
                     "<YourServiceName xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                     "<Number>1001010</Number>\n"
                     "<Feedback>Something feedback</Feedback>\n"
                     "</YourServiceName>\n"
                     "</soap:Body>\n"
                     "</soap:Envelope>\n", Number, Feedback
                     ];

                     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webapp.admin-inapp.com/services/FeedbackService.asmx?op=SendFeedback"];
                    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest     requestWithURL:url];
                   NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
                 [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [theRequest addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tempuri.org/%@",service] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
   [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];
 NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
 responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
 {
NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
 }
```

Comment: username and password ?

Comment: sorry small change. check now