# how to sync core data object to web service in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem regarding to sync core data with web service. My web service is like this

```
POST /webservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: Url
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Method"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Method xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <key1>int</key1>
      <key2>long</key2>
      <key3>long</key3>
      <key4>long</key4>
      <key5>long</key5>
      <key6>long</key6>
      <key7>long</key7>
      <key8>long</key8>
      <key9>long</key9>
    </Method>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This how I am saving data in core data

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

                if (self.device) {
                    // Update existing device
                    [device setValue:Audit forKey:@"Key1"];
                    [device setValue:MethodID forKey:@"Key2"];
                    [device setValue:CheckPointID forKey:@"Key3"];
                    [device setValue:GlobalStringChk forKey:@"Key4"];
                    [device setValue:RegionID forKey:@"Key5"];
                    [device setValue:BranchID forKey:@"Key6"];
                    [device setValue:SiteID forKey:@"Key7"];
                    [device setValue:AuID forKey:@"Key8"];
                    [device setValue:userid forKey:@"Key9"];

                } else {
                    // Create a new device
                    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity Name" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    [newDevice setValue:Audit forKey:@"Key1"];
                    [newDevice setValue:MethodID forKey:@"Key2"];
                    [newDevice setValue:CheckPointID forKey:@"Key3"];
                    [newDevice setValue:GlobalStringChk forKey:@"Key4"];
                    [newDevice setValue:RegionID forKey:@"Key5"];
                    [newDevice setValue:BranchID forKey:@"Key6"];
                    [newDevice setValue:SiteID forKey:@"Key7"];
                    [newDevice setValue:AuID forKey:@"Key8"];
                    [newDevice setValue:userid forKey:@"Key9"];
                }



                NSError *error = nil;
                // Save the object to persistent store
                if (![context save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                }

 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity Name"];
            self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

This is how I generally used code to post data to web service

```
    -(void)serverconnectionPost{

        NSString *MethodString =@"?op=Method";
        NSString *ServerfullString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ServerString,MethodString];

        int auid=0;
        long regionid=[RegionID longLongValue];
        long branch=[BranchID longLongValue];
        long site=[SiteID longLongValue];
        long auditnameid=[AuditNameId longLongValue];
        long checkpoint=[CheckPointID longLongValue];
        long methodofmeasume=[MethodID longLongValue];
        long rdbchecklist=[RDBIDCheckListID longLongValue];
        long UserId=[userid longLongValue];

        NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                                 "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                                 "<soap:Body>"
                                 "<Method xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                                 "<Key1>%d</Key1>"
                                 "<Key2>%ld</Key2>"
                                 "<Key3>%ld</Key3>"
                                 "<Key4>%ld</Key4>"
                                 "<Key5>%ld</Key5>"
                                 "<Key6>%ld</Key6>"
                                 "<Key7>%ld</Key7>"
                                 "<Key8>%ld</Key8>"
                                 "<Key9>%ld</Key9>"
                                 "</Method>"
                                 "</soap:Body>"
                                 "</soap:Envelope>",auid,regionid,branch,site,auditnameid,checkpoint,methodofmeasume,rdbchecklist,UserId];

        NSData *postData = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ServerfullString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        NSLog(@"URL = %@",request);
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        myNSUConnectionPOSTObj = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        NSLog(@"Connection link =%@",myNSUConnectionPOSTObj);
        if(myNSUConnectionPOSTObj) {
            myNSMDataFromPOSTServer =[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"Connection Successful");

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
        }
    }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
 [myNSMDataFromPOSTServer setLength:0];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[myNSMDataFromPOSTServer appendData:data];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
 NSXMLParser *myNSXMLParserPostObj=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:myNSMDataFromPOSTServer];
        myNSXMLParserPostObj.delegate=self;
        [myNSXMLParserPostObj parse];
        NSLog(@"%@",myNSXMLParserPostObj.parserError);
        NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: myNSMDataFromPOSTServer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //NSLog(@"Response from Server : %@", responseStringWithEncoded);
        NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
        serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;
        NSString *Str =serverResponse.text;
        NSLog(@"Server Response =%@",Str);
        alert3 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message to display"
                                            message:Str
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert3 show];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
  myMutableStringPOSTObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringPOSTObj);
    NSData *dataPost = [myMutableStringPOSTObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsePOSTdict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataPost options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsePOSTdict);
}

-(IBAction)joinbtnClick:(id)sender
{
    [self serverconnectionPost];
}
```

Note - ServerString contain url of Web service.

I need to sync one value with web service then delete it from core data then another value just like sync.

How to sync core data to web service.Did anybody done this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why are you not using AFNetworking framework to post data?? Its very simple and will handle all the required scenarios.

Comment: @VishalSonawane I am using XMLParsing  and AFNetworking is for JSON Parsing. I am not sure when I search I get AFNNetworking for JSON Parsing.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If devices comes from Core Data it cannot contain NSString. Either it's NSManagedObject or NSDictionary. I guess it's NSManagedObject.

In this case it's more suitable to use the NSManagedObject as object in the loop and get the values for the nine keys respectively:

```
 for (NSManagedObject *object in devices) {

        NSSString *string1 = [object valueForKey:@"key1"];
        NSSString *string2 = [object valueForKey:@"key2"];
        NSSString *string3 = [object valueForKey:@"key3"];
        NSSString *string4 = [object valueForKey:@"key4"];
        NSSString *string5 = [object valueForKey:@"key5"];
        NSSString *string6 = [object valueForKey:@"key6"];
        NSSString *string7 = [object valueForKey:@"key7"];
        NSSString *string8 = [object valueForKey:@"key8"];
        NSSString *string9 = [object valueForKey:@"key9"];
        // use the strings

//Hear call your method...It will send value one by one to web service.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `AFNetworking` framework to handle all the networking related operations either parsing `JSON` data or `XML` data. To parse `XML` data you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402034/parsing-xml-with-afnetworking) answer.

For more information on AFNetworking see [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

**EDIT:**
Follow [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1) tutorial to get an idea about posting core data to server.

Comment: Thanks of response. I am able to post data. I want code or hint for how to sync core data object to web service.